# Cannot set property 'onfocus' of null

Tags: javascript, html

even the id of the input password exists I still have  error appearing in  onfocus function  
and this is a snippit of my code

```js
let myInput = document.getElementById("pwd"); 

myInput.onfocus = function () {
    document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
}

myInput.onblur = function () {
    document.getElementById("message").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
                                </span>
                                <input name="user_password" id="pwd" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" type="password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="message">

                            ....
                        
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: I do not see element having `id` as `message`...

Comment: where is your element with id="message"

Comment: Also generally it's better to avoid the "archaic"  events such as `onclick` `onfocus` etc and it's better to utilize the `addEventListener`, especially if it's followed by an IIFE function

Answer (score 0):

Issue with your code is ID with `"message"` does not exist hence your are finding this error.

```js
let myInput = document.getElementById("pwd");
myInput.onfocus = function() {
  document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
}
myInput.onblur = function() {
  document.getElementById("message").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>
  <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
                                </span>
      <input name="user_password" id="pwd" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" type="password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="message" style="display:none">Message goes here</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be working fine, after you have added a `div` with `id=message`

```js
let myInput = document.getElementById("pwd"); 

myInput.onfocus = function () {
    document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
}

myInput.onblur = function () {
    document.getElementById("message").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>
  <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
      </span>
      <input name="user_password" id="pwd" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" type="password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="message">
    ....
  </div>
</div>
```